# An approximation to compute the inverse function of Riemann zeta function numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-zeta

Consider Riemann zeta function on the domain $\{x|x>1\}$. Is there a way to compute its inverse function ($F(s)$ such that $F(\zeta(s)) = s$) numerically approximately, except for interpolation?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72529/inverse-of-the-riemann-zeta-function). Anyway I dont found something more specific.

Comment: Maybe you can provide us more details @user1952009 Many thanks.

Comment: I hope don't disturb, I am saying explicit and detailed calculations to understand the development of the solution. Many thanks @user1952009

Comment: @user243301 detailed calculation about what ? do you understand what is a math question ?

Comment: @user1952009 that's what I meant

Comment: Then do you know this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235470/proving-theorem-connecting-the-inverse-of-a-holomorphic-function-to-a-contour-in

Comment: @user1952009 I think that's a good solution. Thanks!