# What is the Lambert's solution of $x = q+x^m$?

Tags: lambert-w

In 1758, Lambert solved the trinomial equation $x = q+x^m$ by giving a series development for $x$ in powers of $q$ as stated in [On the Lambert W function (2nd page)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf).

Looking for the series solution of $x = q+x^m$ and the detailed process by which it was solved.

(I have done a lot of searching but couldn't find it anywhere.)

Comment: The paper you link has a citation of Lambert's 1758 paper. Have you checked that?

Comment: Moreover, there's an MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118532/what-was-lamberts-solution-to-xmx-q , and the question has a link to the paper.

Comment: @Chappers http://www.kuttaka.org/~JHL/L1758c.pdf this paper is in foreign language. Also the answer in mathoverflow does not include how the problem was solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Chappers the trinomial equation in the mathoverflow question is slightly different.

Comment: In general for solving $P(z) = a$ you'll need [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878306/276986) for $P^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use solve $x=q+x^{n+1}$ using power series in $q$. The idea is to use an iterative process with $x_0=q+O(q^2)$ and $x_{k+1}=q+x_k^{n+1}$. In the limit we get $$x = q + q^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{2n+1}+(n+1)(3n+2)/2x^{3n+1}+\cdots$$
where the coefficients are OEIS sequence [A070914](http://oeis.org/A070914).
In general, you could use the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).
See the example in the Wikipedia article which also mentions Lambert W.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Is this equation solvable using Lambert's W function?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. W is for exponential equations.